# nginx rewrites with exclusions

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I have a site which recently changed its page structure to add the ability for multiple languages (`/en/` for English, `/fr/` for French). I have the following rewrite rules in `my server {}` block:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ @abc;
    location @abc {
            if ($uri !~ "^/(.*)\/(.*)$") {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /en/$1 permanent;
            }
            rewrite ^/(.*)\/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2;
    }
    rewrite ^/$ /en/$1 permanent;
```

It's a little bit of a mess, but I can't seem to accomplish what I need:

- All links accessed should be checked to see if the file exists (works)
- All 'old' links such as `/abc` should be 301'd to `/en/abc` (works, but seems hackish)
- The root of the site should be redirected to `/en/` (works)
- Links in the format `/en/abc` should be sent to `index.php` as `?lang=$1&page=$2` (this includes `/en/abc/123` where `abc/123` is `$2` and `en` is `$1`). `$2` can have any length, such as `abc/123/456`

What I have 'seems' to work fine, but sub pages `abc/123` seem to set `$1` to `en/abc` and `$2` to `123` which isn't desired and results in a 404 error as the script can't find the page `123`. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
try_files $uri $uri/ @abc;
location @abc {
        if ($uri !~ "^/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$") {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /en/$1 permanent;
        }
        rewrite ^/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2;
}
rewrite ^/$ /en/$1 permanent;
```

I have replace `.*` with `[^\/]*`.

Comment: I've taken your [^\/]* and tweaked it a little, as the second [^\/]* seemed to cause a redirect loop? http://paste2.org/p/1507931 is the revised version. Thanks for the help! (I don't have enough rep to up vote the answer, but I would if I could!)